# luatex: token.set_macro() issue

Tags: luatex, expansion

In the MWE below, I first define `\command(A|B|C|D)` which expands to `\cmd(A|B|C|D)` which all expand to `THE COMMAND`. None of these use `\edef`, so I should have no issue with defining `\commandX` first. But what I do notice, is if I use the `lua` function `token.set_macro` to define `\commandB -> \cmdB` first then `\cmdB -> THE COMMAND`, the results are not identical to and the `\` seems to be ignored. However, if I swap the order, it works as expected. Perhaps this is a bug? Please note, I also tested this in a separate `.lua` file, this is not a `luacode` issue.

I expect to see THE COMMAND four times. The result I get is:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}

% \edef\commandA{\cmdE} % error, because \cmd is not defined yet
% \edef\cmdE{THE COMMAND} %

\gdef\commandA{\cmdA}
\gdef\cmdA{THE COMMAND}

\begin{luacode*}
  -- the problem: the \\ seems to be ignored
  token.set_macro('commandB', '\\cmdB', 'global')
  token.set_macro('cmdB', 'THE COMMAND', 'global')
  
  -- but if I do define \cmdC first, it accepts it as I like
  token.set_macro('cmdC', 'THE COMMAND', 'global')
  token.set_macro('commandC', '\\cmdC', 'global')
  
  -- should I forego token.set_macro and just do this?
  tex.print('\\gdef\\commandD{\\cmdD}')
  tex.print('\\gdef\\cmdD{THE COMMAND}')
\end{luacode*}

\commandA\\
\commandB\\
\commandC\\
\commandD

% https://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/luatex.pdf
% manual page 217 says "the results are like \gdef
  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a warning in the luatex manual somewhere about this. `token.set_macro` really needs the token to be already in the hash table.

If you split up your code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}

% \edef\commandA{\cmdE} % error, because \cmd is not defined yet
% \edef\cmdE{THE COMMAND} %

\gdef\commandA{\cmdA}
\gdef\cmdA{THE COMMAND}

\begin{luacode*}
  -- the problem: the \\ seems to be ignored
  token.set_macro('commandB', '\\cmdB', 'global')
\end{luacode*}

\show\commandB
```

then it reports

```
> \commandB=macro:
->BADcmdB.
l.16 \show\commandB
                 
?
```

as `\cmdB` did not refer to an entry in the hash table of csnames.

If you do more or less anything earlier using  that `\cmdB` csname then it works as you expect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}

% \edef\commandA{\cmdE} % error, because \cmd is not defined yet
% \edef\cmdE{THE COMMAND} %

\gdef\commandA{\cmdA}
\gdef\cmdA{THE COMMAND}
\def\wibble{\cmdB}

\begin{luacode*}
  -- the problem: the \\ seems to be ignored
  token.set_macro('commandB', '\\cmdB', 'global')
\end{luacode*}

\show\commandB
```

makes

```
> \commandB=macro:
->\cmdB .
l.17 \show\commandB
                 
?
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you for sharing. Are there any disadvantages to `tex.print('\\gdef\\commandB{\\cmdB}')` that come to mind? Note that I would be doing this in the pre-amble if it means anything.

Comment: @likethevegetable well tex.print is of course much slower you have to package the lua string pass it back to tex, get tex to reparse the string as tex tokens and then make the assignment, whereas  token.set is probably just a couple of pointer assignments (I didn't check the code) but unless you are in a tight loop doing millions of these it probably is not actually observable, and as you see the optimisation comes at a price of dark corners where dragons lurk.